# Firebase время сервера

Tags: java, android

Есть чат на firebase. Необходимо при отправлении сообщения задавать ему время в миллисекундах. Причем некоторые пользователи криво настраивают время на своих телефонах, из-за этого необходимо брать время из интернета.

Вопрос. Есть ли простая возможность получить миллисекунды посредством firebase, если нет, то каким образом вы решили такую проблему?

П.с. в интернете миллион вариантов решения этой проблемы, но я не нашел чтобы была возможность запрашивать время 1-2 строками кода, заранее спасибо.

Comment: Возможно, вам надо передавать константу ServerValue.TIME_STAMP в виде значения времени  https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-api/javadoc/com/firebase/client/ServerValue.html

Comment: Вот так попробуйте: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36659507/3212712